# Strange Full-Text Search behavior for some noise word

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I recognized that word "after" realy strange behave when I run FTS.
At first "after" is noise word, so sql should exclude it from select, because option 'transform noise words' is 1 on my enviroment (SQL 2012);

if I run

```
    SELECT p.name,  tbl.* FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.PaperPdfs, *, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL ,   after) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL , plasma) ') tbl
```

I do not recieve any rows. WHY???

If I run

```
    SELECT p.name,  tbl.* FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.PaperPdfs, *, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL ,   the) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL , plasma) ') tbl
```

("the" also is noise word)

or even

```
    SELECT p.name,  tbl.* FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.PaperPdfs, *, 'FORMSOF(THESAURUS,   after) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL , plasma) ') tbl
```

I recieved some results. I have found only one such "strange" word this is "after", but I was very worried about it.

Comment: Are you *sure* 'after' is treated as a 'noise' word? Perhaps it's not, and you simply have no FTS indexed rows which contain it.

Comment: I am sure that "after" is noise word. Even "after" is not noise word I know documents which contains this word and it should be selected in this case.

Comment: Well, that's vexing, then... hmmm...

Comment: Do you get results with just `'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, after)'` or even just `'after'`?

Comment: No, but this I can explain, because 'after' is noise word

Comment: Can somebody try to repeat this on hisown server? I can repro it on two different servers and two different databases.